# How to render different background image for each page of multi-page Sveltekit site

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am building a multi page site using Sveltekit. The design calls for a different background image for each page. My initial idea was to use the :global style attribute to set the image on each page:

```
<style>
    :global(body) {
        background-image: url('image-for-this-page.png');
    }
</style>
```

This works, but only the first time each page is rendered. Any navigation back to a previously rendered page will **not** change back to the background image assigned to that page, it just keeps the most recently loaded image (unless the whole site is refreshed through the browser).
I'm still really new to Sveltekit, is there a specific Sveltekit API I should be looking to use in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work, because it will just append these styles the entire time, resulting in only the first one being used.

If I would want this I would use a helper lifecycle method, that sets the background inline.

```js
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

export function setBackground(background) {
  onMount(() => {
    let current = document.body.style['background-image'];
    document.body.style['background-mage'] = background;
    return () =>  document.body.style['background-image'] = current;
  })
}
```

And you can simply use it in your pages like this:

```js
import { setBackground } from '/background.js';
setBackground('path/to/image');
```

The `current` part in the script ensures that when navigating away, the background will be set to the original version, this can be useful if most pages have the same background, but only some have a different one.